# yum installs 'provides' package before actual 'required' package

Tags: rpm, yum

I have a yum repo which contains the rpm packages A - F.

- Package A requires package B
- Package B conflicts with packages E-F
- Package C provides package B and requires D-F

When I do a '**yum install -y A**' on a clean system, I'm expecting package A to be installed and to require package B to be installed, but package C-F are installed instead.

Why? Does a "Provides:" out rank a "Required:"? What is the hierarchy or decision flow when doing a yum install?

Answer (score 0):

For `rpm` there is no distinction between a "real" and a "virtual" provides. For `rpm`, these are the same:

- package **C** providing **B**
- package **B**

So `yum` handles your request something like this:

- you want to install package **A**
- package **A** requires **B**
- yum finds the first package that fulfills this requirement (bad luck, **C** in your case)

Comment: But B was not installed.   The system was clean.  The only command given was "yum install A".  The "yum install A"  pulled in C (and all of C's requirements) instead of B, where B is explicitly required by A.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, but the core answer remains the same: yum cannot differentiate.